# Javascript Google Maps Marker Array Returning Incorrect Length

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have declared an array variable in JS with dynamically named elements created for every new element in the array.

However, when trying to count the number of elements in the array, I'm getting 0.

What am I doing incorrectly?? Thanks!!

```
var cityMarkers = [];

cityMarkers[element.name] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
       ...
});

[Piacenza: _.te, Voghera: _.te, Valenza: _.te]
Piacenza: _.te {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.K, gm_bindings_: {…}, map: Wf, …} 
Valenza: _.te {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.K, gm_bindings_: {…}, map: Wf, …}
Voghera: _.te {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.K, gm_bindings_: {…}, map: Wf, …}
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)`
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
cityMarkers[element.name] = new google.maps.Marker({
  ...
})
```

you don't actually add things to the array, but you treat this array as a regular object instead for which you define 'regular' properties (JS arrays, like functions are special kinds of objects, so they allow treating like this). That's why the property `length` is still `0`.